# C++ Corrupted Heap

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, free, realloc

My program seems to throw a rune-time exception about a corrupted heap when the main method returns. I have taken the proper precautions to not have this happen, including a copy constructor. Could anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

MyString.cpp

```
#include "MyString.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

MyString::MyString() {
    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    *str = '\0';
}

MyString::MyString(char* src) {
    int size = sizeof(char)*(strlen(src) + 1);
    str = (char*)malloc(size);
    strcpy_s(str, size, src);
}


MyString MyString::operator+(char* add) {
    int addSize = sizeof(char)*strlen(add);
    int fullSize = sizeof(char)*(strlen(str) + 1) + addSize;
    str = (char*)realloc(str, fullSize);
    char* temp = str;
    temp += strlen(str);
    strcpy_s(temp, addSize + 1, add);
    return *this;
}

MyString::~MyString() {
    if (str)
        free(str);
}

MyString::MyString(const MyString &arg) {
    int size = sizeof(char) * (strlen(arg.str) + 1);
    str = (char*)malloc(size);
    strcpy_s(str, size, arg.str);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyString.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MyString test = MyString("hello!");
    test = test + " world";
    cout << test.toString() << endl;
    cout << strlen(test.toString()) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0; //runtime error here
}
```

Comment: Where is toString defined

Comment: What is in "MyString.h"?

Comment: I would encourage to use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Should be getting a compiler warning at `test = test + " world";` because `" world"` is a `const char *`, not a `char *`. Same with `MyString test = MyString("hello!");`

Comment: Normally I would agree @grigor , but then the `realloc` trick they use later would be a bit nasty.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic, requires [mcve], because it's been about 45 minutes since missing information was requested and it has not been supplied. What has been posted is flawed, but not fatally so; the cause of the crash cannot be determined without the complete definition and implementation `MyString`. The two answers so far are probably correct, but this can't be proved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fixing my post according to @user4581301 suggestion:

You sholud modify your addition operator overload so it spawns a new object and also implement assigment operator overload like this:

```
MyString operator+(char* add) const {
    int thisSize = sizeof(char)*strlen(str);
    int addSize = sizeof(char)*(strlen(add) + 1);
    int fullSize = thisSize + addSize;

    char* tempStr = (char*)malloc(fullSize);
    strcpy_s(tempStr, fullSize, str);
    strcpy_s(tempStr + thisSize, fullSize, add);

    return MyString(tempStr);
}

MyString& operator=(const MyString& assign){

    int assignSize = sizeof(char)*(strlen(assign.str) + 1);

    str = (char*)realloc(str, assignSize);

    strcpy_s(str, assignSize, assign.str);

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: There is a really good trick that uses `+=` to implement `+` covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn about [Rule Of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Implicit assigment operator is used and when the old object is destroyed new one uses already freed pointer and later it tries to free it again.

Comment: Very high likelihood you are correct. `test = test + " world";` may well be fatal, but we need to see `operator=` implementation, if any, to be sure. The copy constructor and destructor look Rule of Three compliant and we have not seen the assignment operator. Until then, the best we can do is guess.